# lua logitech script not working after standby

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Hi I'm new to lua programming. I'm trying to get a simple script to work but I can't figure out why it doesn't loop. The debug shows no errors and the console correctly returns the events to me at each mouse click. If I put the outputlogmessage function inside the first loop it doesn't print anything on the screen. I take it that it does not enter the cycle. Can anyone help me, I guess the solution is trivial but I don't understand.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg:"..arg.."\n")
  if IsMouseButtonPressed(2) then
  repeat    
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
    repeat
      MoveMouseRelative (1,-1)
      Sleep(8)
    until  not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
  until  not IsMouseButtonPressed(2)
  end
end
```

I state that as soon as compiled it worked. After I put the pc in standby and it didn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse buttons enumeration in LGS/GHub is confusing.

For argument of function `IsMouseButtonPressed()`:
1=LMB, 2=MMB, 3=RMB

For value of `arg` (parameter of function `OnEvent`):
1=LMB, 2=RMB, 3=MMB

Please note that right and middle buttons are swapped.
You need to use `IsMouseButtonPressed(3)` for RMB.

Comment: Yes i try but nothing happens. I also try to use button from 6 to 11 but i've found they can't be used in loops. I'm starting to think it's a software problem even though I've already reinstalled the ghub suite three times.

Comment: @samueleCodato - Insert `Sleep(10)` after the line `function OnEvent(event, arg)`

Comment: Insert `EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)` before `function OnEvent(event, arg)`

Comment: You can use buttons 6 and above in a loop. You need to bind action "Back" for physical button 6 in GHub GUI (as if it was button 4) and use `IsMouseButtonPressed(4)` in a loop.  When you press button 6, Windows will see button 4 pressed, so `IsMouseButtonPressed(4)` will return `true`